# What does Apple program Xcode in?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have been wondering:  What does Apple use to program Xcode?  Surely they didn't program it using Xcode itself right?

Was Xcode even programmed in objective-c?

Comment: Why couldn't XCode have been programmed using XCode?  Granted they would have had to bootstrap it with something else initially, but once a certain basic level of capability is reached there's no reason the IDE can't be used to edit its own codebase.  You can use vi to edit the source code for vi, after all.

Comment: You have probably forgotten to take *coffee* today.

Comment: I would assume they wrote it in XCode.  I know that Microsoft writes Visual Studio in itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surely they use Xcode itself. There'd be no reason not to.

Xcode is an IDE -- basically a fancy editor. Just as you could use emacs or vi or TextMate to edit the code that produces those programs, so too could you edit the source for Xcode with Xcode itself.

If you're wondering how the first version of Xcode came about, it was most likely created with Project Builder, which was Xcode's predecessor. And the earliest versions of Project Builder (which originated on NextStep and dates back to the late 1980's) could have been written with any text editor.

Answer (score 1):

Thats a hard call to make, however it is entirely possible that Xcode is used for Xcode development. After all Xcode can also make OS X apps, which are also written in objective-c.